# Algorithm for Connected Components of Graph

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory

I am looking for the most efficient algorithm in order to find both the number of connected components in a network, and the number of nodes for each connected component.

Example:

Given the following inputs:

```
no_of_nodes = 8

graph_to = [1,1,3,5,6]

graph_from = [2,6,4,7,3]
```

I would receive the following output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 6], [5, 7], [8]]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def connections(no_of_nodes, graph_from, graph_to):

    nodes = list(range(1, no_of_nodes+1))
    
    singles = []
    
    # removes all unconnected nodes

    for node in nodes:
        if node not in graph_from + graph_to:
            singles.append([node])
    
    conns = [[graph_from[0],graph_to[0]]]
    
    graph_from.pop(0)
    graph_to.pop(0)
    
    n=0
    k = 0
    
    while n < len(graph_from):
        
        x = graph_from[n]
        y = graph_to[n]

        if x in conns[k]:
            conns[k].append(y)
            graph_from.pop(n)
            graph_to.pop(n)
        else:
            conns.append([x,y])
            k += 1
            print(conns)
            n+=1
    
    return conns + singles
```

I have found a way to iterate through the nodes assuming that all connections are adjacently placed in the graph_from list, but this, of course, will not hold up for all cases.

EDIT: I am looking for a way to do this without importing a module

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the summarized process answered above, I was able to formulate the following which after testing looks to check out.

```
def connected(graph_nodes, graph_from, graph_to):
 
    
    unseen = [i for i in range(1,graph_nodes + 1)]
    
    edges = [[graph_from[i],graph_to[i]] for i in range(len(graph_from))]
    
    
    connects = []
    
    while unseen != []:
        start = unseen[0]
        connection = []

        queue = [start]
        unseen.remove(start)

        while queue != []:

            end = queue[-1]

            if end not in connection:
                connection.append(end)

            queue = queue[:-1]
            
            for k in edges:

                if k[0] == end:
       
                    queue.append(k[1])
                    unseen.remove(k[1])
            
        connects.append(connection)

        
   
    return connects
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [networkx](https://networkx.org/):

```
import networkx as nx

no_of_nodes = 8
graph_to = [1, 1, 3, 5, 6]
graph_from = [2, 6, 4, 7, 3]

g = nx.Graph(zip(graph_from, graph_to))
g.add_nodes_from(range(1, no_of_nodes + 1))

res = list(nx.connected_components(g))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{1, 2, 3, 4, 6}, {5, 7}, {8}]
```

Comment: Thanks - Although, I am looking for a way to do this without a module.

Answer (score 1):

The basic connected set algorithm is:

1. Put all the nodes into a set `unseen`.
2. If `unseen` isn't empty, remove a random element from it and put it onto a queue.  If `unseen` is empty, you're done.
3. While there are elements in the queue, do the following

   - Remove the front element of the queue.
   - Find all `unseen` elements that are connected to that front element.  Remove them from `unseen` and add them to the queue.

   Repeat until the queue is empty.  Once the queue is empty, you have removed one connected component from the graph.  Go back to step 2.

[Edited to improve formatting.  I figured out how to do double nesting]

Comment: Thanks - I believe this worked out. I answered with these steps written out in below. If you could confirm that this looks correct, that would be super helpful!